# '_positions.isNotEmpty': ScrollController not attached to any scroll views.

Tags: flutter, dart

**What is the reason**

Is this the reason _items.isNotEmpty ?

part of the code

```dart
return Column(children: [
      
      _items.isNotEmpty
          ? Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  
                  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: _items.length,
                  
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add controller property to your ListView.

```
ListView.builder(
controller: _scrollController,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you are using the `ScrollController` properties before using it, adding this condition will fix this problem

```
if (_scrollController.hasClients)
```

Comment: I solved it with, `controller: _scrollController,`